# Include roles in login asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have found and tested this code for user login and i wanted to
 display user data after the login on his profile page and i did it
 with session (I hope i did it good), but i dont know how to add role
 based authorization in mine sql procedure and login code. Please help
 i am new in this. This is my code on login page:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (AuthenticateUser(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtEmail.Text, CheckBoxRememberMe.Checked);

        string user =txtEmail.Text.Trim();
        Session["user"] = user;

    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Email and/or Password";
    }
}
private bool AuthenticateUser(string Email, string password)
{

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAuthenticateUser", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        string EncryptedPassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "SHA1");

        SqlParameter paramEmail = new SqlParameter("@Email", Email);
        SqlParameter paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", EncryptedPassword);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramEmail);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassword);

        con.Open();
        int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return ReturnCode == 1;
    }
}
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
USE [BMEos]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spAuthenticateUser]
@Email nvarchar(100),
@Password nvarchar(100)
as
Begin
 Declare @Count int

 Select @Count = COUNT(Email) from tblUsers
 where [Email] = @Email and [Password] = @Password

 if(@Count = 1)
 Begin
  Select 1 as ReturnCode
 End
 Else
 Begin
  Select -1 as ReturnCode
 End
End
```

This is my profile page

```
public partial class MainPages_Profile : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["User"] != null)
        {          
                con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=JOSIPPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BMEos;Integrated Security=True";
                con.Open();
                showdata();           
        }
        else
        {

            }
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void showdata()
    {     
        cmd.CommandText = "Select* from tblUsers where Email = '" + Session["user"] + "'";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(ds);
        Label1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString() + "&nbsp;" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josip, are you talking about SQL Security?  That is, do you want the procedure and/or login to only work for people within an active directory group?

If so, you need to set up the security on the SQL Server side & let SQL Server determine what is accessible.  You first set up a login and then associate a user with that login (typically both use the same name).

To create the login, you need to have sysadmin access to the SQL Server & create the login in the master database (you can use SSMS or T-SQL).  T-SQL:

```
use master
go
create login [DOMAINNAME\username] from windows with default_language=[us_english], DEFAULT_DATABASE=[databasename]
create user [DOMAINNAME\username] from login [DOMAINNAME\username] with DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo]
```

Then you need to link the user to the database you want them to have access to. 
 Again, you can use SSMS or T-SQL:

```
use [databasename]
go
create user [DOMAINNAME\username] from login [DOMAINNAME\username] with DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', [DOMAINNAME\username]
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', [DOMAINNAME\username]
grant execute on object::dbo.yourstoredprocedure to [DOMAINNAME\username]
```

If you don't want to do this for each and every user, then set up an active directory security group and perform the above actions on the security group.  In this manner, you can add users to the security group to provide privileges to the database side of things.

Ultimately, it is best to have database access locked down as much as possible.  Try and give permissions only to those individuals or groups that require it & only provide those permissions they need.  [Stay away from granting everyone the sysadmin role!!!]